# Adding ID column matching values from another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame arranged as follows

```
df <- structure(list(NAME1    =  c("AAA","CCC", "BBB", "BBB"), 
             NAME2            =  c("BBB", "AAA","DDD", "AAA"),
             ID1              =  c(1,3,2,2),
             ID2              =  c(2,1,4,1)),
        .Names                =  c("NAME1","NAME2","ID1","ID2"), 
        row.names             =  c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class =("data.frame"))
```

I have another data frame (df1) and would like to add an ID column. The ID values should be the same as in df. The desired data frame should look like this.

```
df1 <- structure(list(NAME         =  c("AAA","BBB", "CCC", "DDD"), 
                      SIZE         =  c(0.9, 1.7, 1.4, 1.1),                     
                       ID          =  c(1,2,3,4)),
                .Names             =  c("NAME","SIZE", "ID"), 
                row.names          =  c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class =("data.frame"))
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: Use `match` or `merge`   It is not clear though

Comment: yup. Unclear to me as well. How do you get `ID` column?

Comment: Sorry if the question seems unclear. The `ID` column simply consists of the ID values in df.This is an attempt `df1$ID <- df$ID1[match(df$NAME1, df1$NAME)]`, `df1$ID <- df$ID2[match(df$NAME2, df1$NAME)]`

Comment: Are you saying that the match should be done sequentially on each ID column?

Answer (score 1):

You should reformat your "key", at which point, it should be easy to merge to get the new IDs.

Example:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
setDT(df1)
df1[, ID := NULL][] ## I assume you're starting without an ID
df1
#    NAME SIZE
# 1:  AAA  0.9
# 2:  BBB  1.7
# 3:  CCC  1.4
# 4:  DDD  1.1

idkey <- unique(melt(df, measure.vars = patterns("NAME", "ID"),
                     value.name = c("NAME", "ID")), 
                by = c("NAME", "ID"))[, c("NAME", "ID"), with = FALSE]

idkey
#    NAME ID
# 1:  AAA  1
# 2:  CCC  3
# 3:  BBB  2
# 4:  DDD  4

df1[idkey, on = "NAME"]
#    NAME SIZE ID
# 1:  AAA  0.9  1
# 2:  CCC  1.4  3
# 3:  BBB  1.7  2
# 4:  DDD  1.1  4
```

---

The base R approach might be something like:

```
idkey <- unique(
  data.frame(NAME = unlist(df[grep("NAME", names(df))], use.names = FALSE), 
             ID = unlist(df[grep("ID", names(df))], use.names = FALSE)))
merge(df1, idkey, by = "NAME")
#   NAME SIZE ID
# 1  AAA  0.9  1
# 2  BBB  1.7  2
# 3  CCC  1.4  3
# 4  DDD  1.1  4
```